Unable to share entire screen on google meet
Environment:

OS: Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm)
Release: 12


I'm trying to share my screen using Google Chrome or Firefox-ESR and I only can share the browser, I can't share my entire screen

Please [edit] your question and clarify what "can't" means here. Does the browser crash? Does it think it is sharing but in fact showing a black screen? Is the screen flickering madly with different windows appearing and disappearing? Something else? Also, tell us if you are using Wayland or X, give us the details of your graphics card and driver (see inxi -G), and also tell us what desktop environment you are using.
